# MySQL Workbench - script storing return in array and performing calculations?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Firstly, this is part of my college homework.

Now that's out of the way: I need to write a query that will get the number of free apps in a DB as a percentage of the total number of apps, sorted by what category the app is in.

I can get the number of free apps and also the number of total apps by category. Now I need to find the percentage, this is where it goes a bit pear-shaped.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    -- find total number of apps per category
    select @totalAppsPerCategory := count(*), category_primary
    from apps
    group by category_primary;

    -- find number of free apps per category
    select @freeAppsPerCategory:= count(*), category_primary
    from apps
    where (price = 0.0)
    group by category_primary;

    -- find percentage of free apps per category
    set @totals = @freeAppsPerCategory / @totalAppsPercategory * 100;
    select @totals, category_primary
    from apps
    group by category_primary;
```

It then lists the categories but the percentage listed in each category is the exact same value.

I had initially thought to use an array, but from what I have read mySql does not seem to support arrays.

I'm a bit lost of how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Since I had been saving the previous results in variables it seems that it was not able to calculate on a row by row basis, which is why all the percentages were identical, it was an average. So the calculation needed to be part of the query.

Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
category_primary,
CONCAT(FORMAT(COUNT(CASE
                WHEN price = 0 THEN 1
            END) / COUNT(*) * 100,
            1),
            '%') AS FreeAppSharePercent
FROM
    apps
GROUP BY category_primary
ORDER BY FreeAppSharePercent DESC;
```

Then the query result is:

[image: QueryResult]